# What's the difference between .pem and public/private keys?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, service, server

I'm creating an instance on AWS, and it's given me a .pem file that will allow me to connect to my instance.

I always use public/private keys to connect to remote servers.

I'd like to know what's the difference between these methods on AWS.

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43697/what-is-the-difference-between-pem-csr-key-and-crt

Answer (score 2):

You can ask AWS to create a public/private key in the Amazon EC2 console. When you do this, AWS retains the public key and downloads the private key (`.pem`) to you. Make sure you save it, because you can't get the private key again.

Alternatively, you can create your own public/private key outside of AWS. You can then **Import** the key into the Amazon EC2 console.

In both cases, the key is then available to select when launching an Amazon EC2 instance. When an AMI provided by AWS is used for the new instance, software on the instance will automatically copy the public keypair into the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

For Windows users, a program on the AMI will generate a *random Administrator password*, encrypt the password using the selected keypair, and the user must then provide the private key to decrypt the password. (You are encouraged to change the Administrator password after login.)

If you use Windows and want to use PuTTY to SSH into an Amazon EC2 instance, you will need a `.ppk` file. This can be selected when generating the keypair, or you can use PuTTYGen to convert the key.

**Bottom line:** The `.pem` file is your private key.